# Extend a line network from only its open ends

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-processing, geopandas

I want to extend a dissolved (one single feature) line network from its open ends with the help of either QGIS, PostGIS or any other python package available to use.
[image: example]

Edit: When I run extend tool in QGIS, below is one the results (no matter I change start distance or end distance the result is no different from that)
[image]

Comment: Well, what is keeping your from doing so?

Comment: Have you ever tried using extend in QGIS, it does not only extend from open ends

Comment: This is what happens https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=504700609459

Comment: Ah, so you did try something, which didn't work as intended. Please expand your question accordingly.

Comment: please don't delete and repost questions - it can lead to an automatic suspension

Comment: And that's just happened. As I couldn't receive any answer/comment for the previous one I deleted it and reposted this one